# Server Error 500 Php

Tags: apache, centos, lamp, centos7

Good day

Im trying to install a GamePanel with PHP called Swiftpanel on my VPS Centos7 64bit

i installed LAMP on my vps and html files work perfectly.
But my gamepanel doesnt work

and the gamepanel is located at:

http://51.255.199.40/gpanel/

as you can see when i try reaching my gpanel it gives me the SERVER ERROR 500

i looked at my apache error logs and this is what i get:

```
[Fri Mar 04 15:53:53.533162 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 18753] [client 46.99.59.98:51034] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Here is my httpd.conf and php.conf:

http://pastebin.com/HJfH3gWQ

I need some help fixing this, im a begginer in coding.

With respect

Benjamin Selmani

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf, try changing the line:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

and restart Apache.

Comment: Still 500 Server Error with this in the error Log:



[Fri Mar 04 19:29:20.612198 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 21789] [client 46.99.10.113:53845] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Answer (score 0):

OK, edit your httpd.conf file and change the following line:

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

to:

`Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks`

then restart your Apache server.  If this doesn't work, it's likely we are editing the wrong httpd.conf file.  You'd be surprised how many you might find on your computer including all the conf files in sub directories (look at the last line of your httpd.conf file).  Somewhere there is probably a line that looks like this:

`Options -Indexes`

Which is the explicit cause of the problem.  But try my earlier suggestion first.